# Using WSDL, can we generate other public methods inside a class that is a parameter of a Web Service Method?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Sorry, if the question does not clarify exactly what i need....Please read ahead for the requirement.

I am using JAX-WS 2.2.3.

I have implemented a web service class which has a method *int addRecord(Record)*. The Record  class contains an instance member as collection of Attribute class. Now, the Record class contains a public *void addAttribute(Attribute objAttribute)* method.

I have generated the WSDL for this class using the wsgen ant task.

When i do a wsimport on this WSDL, alon gwith other classes, i only get a Record class that contains set/get methods for the instance member and not the *void addAttribute(Attribute objAttribute)* method.

Is there a way to get this method also on the Record class?

```
SOURCE CODE:
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```

@XmlType(name = "Record")
public class Record implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
@XmlElement(name = "AttributeList")
List<Attribute> objAttributeList;


public void addAttribute(Attribute objAttribute)
{
    objAttributeList.add(objAttribute);
}
```

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Attribute")
public class Attribute implements Serializable
{
    @XmlElement(name = "Id")
    int id;

```
@XmlElement(name = "Name")
String name;

@XmlElement(name = "Value")
Object value;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

@WebService
class RecordService
{
@WebMethod
public int addRecord(Record objRecord)
{
//code to process record object
}
}

Comment: Have you added the WebMethod annotation to the method ? Can you post your code ?

Comment: @Searock I have edited the post. Sorry for editing it so late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - not with web services.

The system metaphor with web services is message passing. There is a client and a server and they exchange messages via a pre-arranged communication protocol or contract. The messages and the exchanges are described in WSDL.

What you are imagining is a distributed object system, where you transmit *objects* and not messages. This is generally not the model that web services tools (for any platform) support.

Consider changing your architecture to use DTOs - [Data Transfer Objects](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) - for the things that get exchanged. Then implement logic in different business-level objects that maybe use the [Adapter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) to slurp their state from the DTO. The business objects could be shared data types, if you like; in other words a single JAR that defines the type and gets referenced from within client and from within server.